# R model.matrix and the tilde operator usage?

Tags: r

I'm messing around with R and came across some code using the tilde operator and Model.Matrix in a way I can't really quite figure out. I produced a very simple example below.

```
data("iris")

x = model.matrix(~Species +0, iris)
x
```

Here's a quick snapshot of the data selecting 3 random rows with different species:

```
>iris[c(1,78, 143),]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
78           6.7         3.0          5.0         1.7 versicolor
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
```

and of the same row but after it's been put through model.matrix:

```
> x[c(1,78,143),]
    Speciessetosa Speciesversicolor Speciesvirginica
1               1                 0                0
78              0                 1                0
143             0                 0                1
```

As you can see this output output creates a matrix of 3 columns, and 150 rows (the same number of observations). In each row the corresponding species of flower is labeled 1. This is really neat but I can't really understand how or why this is working exactly.

I'm confused on two elements.

1. what exactly is model.matrix doing here. When I bring up the help menu in RStudio it simply  `model.matrix creates a design (or model) matrix, e.g., by expanding factors to a set of dummy variables (depending on the contrasts) and expanding interactions similarly.`

I don't really quite follow what this means. What does it mean when it says "expanding factors" to a set of dummy variables?

2. Also, how is the tilde operator being used here? Usually when I have seen the tilde operator, it separates the Y and the Xs as in `lm(Y ~ X1+X2-X3)` or the like. I've never seen it used nakedly here.

if I just run something similar in the console without the wrapping of model.matrix like so:

```
> ~iris$Species
```

I only get this as the output:

```
~iris$Species
```

Which honestly seems like an error, but I  assume since R doesn't tell me it is an error that it's not actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot here, let's go point by point. The main idea is that `model.matrix()` is designed to take the variables in your data set and transform them into a matrix format that is suitable for linear regression (you may be familiar with the linear-algebra expression for regression, `y = X %*% beta`).

For simple numerical covariates, the translation is simple — the variable becomes a column in `X`. Categorical variables (factors in R), however, have to be transformed to a set of binary variables that will represent differences in expected responses across categories, in a way that is defined by the *contrasts* associated with the factors.

`~Species +0` says to set up dummy variables for the `Species` factor: `+0` says not to use an intercept. In this special case, the dummy variables created are *indicator variables* — for a given row, the value in the column corresponding to the species for that observation is 1, the others are 0. Since (for example) the first observation is of "Setosa", `Speciessetosa` is 1, the other columns are zero.  If you had a vector of coefficients (`beta`) that contained the mean for each species, multiplying this `X %*% beta` would pick out the mean corresponding to the species for each observation.

(The R formula language is quite a rabbit hole: it can do useful, complicated stuff if the formula contains factors with different contrasts; interactions; or functions such as `poly()` or `splines::ns()` that create multi-variable predictors from a single input variable ...)

Question 2: in `<response> ~ <stuff>`, the `<stuff>` contains the input variables we need to define the model matrix. Until we actually fit the regression model, we don't need to know the response variable, so we can use a *one-sided formula* `~ <stuff>`.

Your last question: using `~` **outside of a formula context** tells R to keep whatever follows the tilde as an *unevaluated expression*. For example:

```r
> x <- ~hello
> x
~hello
> x[[2]]
hello
> hello <- 5
> eval(x[[2]])
[1] 5
```